# Round # With 1% Accuracy and Convert to Scientific Notation

Tags: php, rounding, scientific-notation

I have millions of long numbers (`5216672577`) in CSV data files and I'd like to reduce the file size. I plan to do this by rounding as many of the trailing digits as possible to 0, while staying within `X`% accuracy to the original number. Then I will convert the numbers to scientific notation. I prefer the format `103e7` to `1.03E+7`. The period and plus symbols add unnecessary bytes. I'm working with integers.

**Update - I got it to work:**

```
for($i = 9000; $i < 11000; $i++) {
    echo notation($i), "\r\n<br>";
}

// Round and abbreviate an integer
function notation($int, $precision=0.01) {
    // We cannot shorten small numbers
    if(is_int($int) && $int >= 1000) {
        $best = $int;

        // For each decimal place
        $l = strlen($int);
        for($i = 3; $i <= $l - 1; $i++) {

            // Round to the deciaml place
            $newInt = round($int, -$i);

            // Check precision
            $ratio = $int / $newInt;
            if($ratio < (1 - $precision) || $ratio > (1 + $precision)) {
                break;
            }

            // Save the best option
            $best = $newInt;
        }

        // Count and remove trailing zeros
        $l = strlen($best);
        $best = rtrim($best, '0');
        $i = $l - strlen($best);

        // Check that we can actually shorten the int
        if ($i >= 3) {
            // Add scientific Notation
            return $best . 'e' . $i;
        }
    }
    return $int;
}
```

Comment: The `PHP_INT_MAX` constant determines the maximum number that can be handled as integer. You're possibly running 32-bit PHP so you cannot use integers. You need to use strings and some arbitrary precision library such as [bcmath](http://php.net/bcmath) or [GMP](http://php.net/gmp).

Comment: You can keep the current accuracy and occupy less space by encoding them to a different numeric base? Rather than base64 here is a  base62 encoder / decoder - https://gist.github.com/Synchro/1139429

Comment: I got it work. Thanks for the input. My numbers aren't larger than 32-bits.

Comment: You can also compress the file.

Comment: I assumed 5,216,672,577 was an example of large number and it's greater than 32-bit `PHP_INT_MAX` (which is 2,147,483,647). Is it just the row count?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It's an example number. I was counting the digits as 10/32, so my mistake. I'm on a 64-bit system now, but may be switching to a 32-bit system, so your comment is helpful. Thank you.